# Is it possible to style groups of elements that have the same attribute value together?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The HTML for my application looks something like this:

```
<div class="chat">
  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">Hello Bob!<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">How are you today?<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">I am doing great myself!<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Bob">
    <div class="content">Hey Alice!<div>
    <div class="author">Bob</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Bob">
    <div class="content">Nice hearing from you :-)<div>
    <div class="author">Bob</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to create some styling that works on the *group* of all messages that have the same author, such as hiding the `.author` child element except on the last-child.

Is there a way to do this using CSS attribute selectors or other CSS features? (Is it possible to do this *without* altering the HTML)?

Comment: _“a chat application, which should be easy to style”_ - for others, who will use your component in their app/website later on? Then you probably don’t want to get too “fancy” with CSS selectors in the first place. // Attribute selectors won’t help you much here, even in combination with adjacent sibling or stuff like that - to determine that some item was the last of its – only imaginary – “group” here, it would have to look at the _next_ item - and that’s not how CSS selectors work.

Comment: Actually grouping consecutive messages by the same author into a container element would make _much_ more sense here IMHO, to be able to easily apply the kind of formatting you want (last child of “group”, etc.) Should be easy enough to achieve if the whole shebang is output in one go; if messages are appended gradually on the client, it might be worth investing a bit more into the grouping logic there, so that CSS finally has a structure it can easily operate on in the desired ways.

Comment: @misorude You might be right. I'll investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the author's name that you want to target, you can do this:

```css
.message[data-author="Bob"]{
   color:red;
}
.message[data-author="Alice"]{
   color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">Hello Bob!<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">How are you today?<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message" data-author="Alice">
    <div class="content">I am doing great myself!<div>
    <div class="author">Alice</div>
  </div>


  <div class="message" data-author="Bob">
    <div class="content">Hey Alice!<div>
    <div class="author">Bob</div>
  </div>


  <div class="message" data-author="Bob">
    <div class="content">Nice hearing from you :-)<div>
    <div class="author">Bob</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes @Arkellys you are right this only work when we know the authors names.

Comment: Since this solution only works if the authors' names are known, I cannot use this solution =/

Comment: then may be you need jquery or javascript for that i think using css its not possible